# JQ to convert JSON to CSV for specific Keys

Tags: json, bash, csv, jq

I am trying to convert JSON to CSV for selected keys using `jq`.

file.json

```json
{
  "_ref": "ipv4address/Li5pcHY0X2FkZHJlc3yMDIuMS8w:10.202.202.1",
  "discovered_data": {
    "bgp_as": 64638,
    "device_model": "catalyst37xxStack",
    "device_port_name": "Vl2002",
    "device_port_type": "propVirtual",
    "device_type": "Switch-Router",
    "device_vendor": "Cisco",
    "discovered_name": "Test_Device.network.local",
    "discoverer": "Network Insight",
    "first_discovered": 1580161888,
    "last_discovered": 1630773758,
    "mac_address": "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff",
    "mgmt_ip_address": "10.202.202.1",
    "os": "15.2(4)E10",
    "port_speed": "Unknown",
    "port_vlan_name": "TEST-DATA",
    "port_vlan_number": 2002
  },
  "ip_address": "10.202.202.1",
  "is_conflict": false,
  "mac_address": "",
  "names": ["Test_Device"],
  "network": "10.202.202.0/23",
  "network_view": "TEST VIEW",
  "objects": [],
  "status": "USED",
  "types": [
    "UNMANAGED"
  ],
  "usage": []
}
```

my desired output is:

```
names,ip_address,discovered_data.mac_address,discovered_data.discovered_name
Test_Device,10.202.202.1,aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,Test_Device.network.local
```

So far, I have tried using following command but getting some syntax error:

```sh
jq -r 'map({names,ip_address,discovered_data.mac_address,discovered_data.discovered_name}) | (first | keys_unsorted) as $keys | map([to_entries[] | .value]) as $rows | $keys,$rows[] | @csv' < file.json
```

Comment: First detail, file.json is missing a `"` at line 22, the IP address.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I was changing my production data so I missed `"` while replacing IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the JSON has been fixed, consider the output of:

```
(null 
| {names,
  ip_address,
  "discovered_data.mac_address",
  "discovered_data.discovered_name"} | keys_unsorted) as $keys
| $keys, 
  ({names: .names[],
   ip_address,
   "discovered_data.mac_address": .discovered_data.mac_address,
   "discovered_data.discovered_name": .discovered_data.discovered_name }
   | [.[]])
| @csv
```

Assuming jq is invoked with the -r command-line option, this has the advantage of producing valid CSV.  If you prefer to have all the key names and values unquoted, you might wish to consider using `join(",")` instead of `@csv`, or some more sophisticated variation if you want to have your cake and eat it.

Comment: This works like a charm, however, I have one issue. The json file from API has square bracket wrapped on the json file and when I issue the command it gives me `jq: error (at <stdin>:32): Cannot index array with string "names"`. Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: Replace `({names:` by `(.[]|{names:`

Comment: That worked beautifully :) . Thank you ! 